# Jenkins API - Connection refused or Error 403

Tags: php, jenkins

I'm trying to manage Jenkins' jobs via an API. By command line, I have no problem accessing data with this line:

`curl  -v --noproxy localhost, http://localhost:4545/job/Test/api/json --user username:token`

(Jenkins is running at `localhost:4545`). The `--noproxy` part is important, otherwise I have a `403 error`.

When I try to do the same in my PHP files, it's not working..

Here my API code:

```
function getLastBuildStatus($url, $jobName, $username, $api_token){
    $ch = initCurl($username, $api_token); //see function downside

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '/job/' . $jobName . '/lastBuild/api/json');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROXY, "localhost"); //return Error:Failed to connect to localhost port 4545: Connection refused
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true); //return Error 403 Access denied

    $result = executeCurl($ch);
    $json = json_decode($result);
    var_dump ($result);
    if($json){
        return $json->result;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }

function initCurl($username, $api_token){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false ); 
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false ); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $api_token); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    return $ch;
}
```

I tried as well to set the proxy but I get an `error 403 forbidden` as well.

Comment: Have you tried setting the user agent or to enable the cookies? E.g. `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');`

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, I tried it and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);` as well, but still the same errors..